# I am trying to build a p2p energy transaction

Tags: addresses, payable

I am trying to build the p2p energy transaction blockchain network.

```
     TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address".
```

--> contract-d3cb9a08a4.sol:142:17:
|
142 |                 msg.sender.transfer(operationalDeposit-fee);
|                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error while running it ,can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the `msg.sender` to the `payable` type:

```js
payable(msg.sender).transfer(operationalDeposit-fee);
```

The `.transfer` method only exists on the `payable address` type **not** on the `address` type.